# Some apps don't accommodate small screen of iPhone SE

Tags: iphone, applications

I rarely install apps because I don't want to navigate the uncertain security implications.  On the few occasions that I do, however, a significant portion of those **apps seem to be designed *only* for phone with larger screens.  Essential parts of the display reside below the bottom edge of the iPhone SE screen.**  Some pages of some apps allow scrolling/panning, but not always.  Sometimes, it seems that they assumed that no one would have a phone so small as to be unable to access the bottom portions of the content, so **the content doesn't scroll, and I can't access the bottom parts.**

For *example,* some parts of the **Tim Hortons app** for reward points allows you to redeem points for food/beverages, but some parts of the menu becomes inaccessible.  Another example is an **app to access a certain vendor's security camera;** it requires that you create an account with the company, but I can only access the login fields -- not the links to create an account, which are below the bottom edge of the display.  I don't know if I can use a friend's bigger phone to create an account, but even if I could, the controls for accessing the video are also way down, and would be inaccessible using my iPhone SE.

I **tried using a pinch gesture** to shrink the size of the content so that the content lower down on the page would fit on the screen.  **Resizing** of the content **doesn't seem to be possible.**

The iPhone SE is not a rare phone.  I can't be the only one butting against this problem.  ***How do others deal with this?***

Comment: "The iPhone SE is not a rare phone." - I tried to verify this by looking at statistics of iPhone shares by model, but the iPhone SE is too old to even get included at all. A year ago this might've been different, but even then it would've been the oldest of 23 iPhone models supported at the time, and the only one with such a small screen.

Comment: I haven't looked all that hard, but I do recall reading only positive accounts of the iPhone SE and people favour its small size.  A quick Google reveals [this](https://www.pcmag.com/news/how-many-iphone-users-will-buy-apples-new-iphone-se) not-too-old article and [this](https://www.macrumors.com/roundup/iphone-se) more recent article.  All I did was [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=how-many-people-own-iphone-se).

Comment: I think we may be talking about different phones then. Are you aware that Apple released three different iPhones over the years that are all just called the "iPhone SE"?

Comment: Like most smartphones, there are successive generations. A quick search indicates that they are the [same size and resolution](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/iphone/iphone-faq/differences-between-iphone-se-a1662-a1723-a1724-models.html). I would expect the same problem to afflict them all, since it is an app design problem, but the only way to be sure is to buy all three generations.

Comment: "A quick search indicates that they are the same size and resolution." - No they're not. The A9 one has a 4.0-inch display (same as the iPhone 5s), and the A13 and A15 ones have a 4.7-inch display (same as the iPhones 6, 6s, 7 and 8).

Comment: Ah, yes, further googling reveals this.  Thank you for correcting me.  The latter 2 generations might avoid the problem in for some apps.  But the fact that apps do not comply with guidelines is still a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is all too common with unsuitable app development and quality assurance practices. I would consider this issue to be a bug with the app that should be reported to the developer. Apps should be able to be used with any text size, but this may help in the short term:

> ### Adjust the text size when you’re using an app
>
> 1. Open Control Center, then tap the Text Size button.
>
>    (If you don’t see the Text Size button, add it to Control Center—go to Settings  > Control Center, then choose Text Size).
> 2. Drag the slider up or down to increase or decrease the text size.
>
> To change the text size for all apps, tap All Apps at the bottom of the screen.

https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/iph3e2e1fb0/ios

Comment: I added Text Size to the control centre.  When using the app, I swiped up and saw the Text Size control.  I could drag the slider down.  Unfortunately, it seems to have no effect on the app screen content.  I tried banishing the app by double-pressing the iPhone's Home button and swiping the app upward.  I restarted the app, but the screen content remained unchanged.  I also re-resized the text, with no effect.  I assume that this is not normal?

Comment: @user There is appropriate code every app should use to read the text size desired set by the user. It sounds like the app developer has not done so — very bad practice — so the text size slider has no effect. You should report this issue to the app developer.

Comment: I will.  The app is designed to access a consumer-grade camera that was made in another country.  This will be an experiment to see how responsive they are to a minority of the market.

Comment: @user The text size slider is mainly an accessibility feature to increase the size in apps with text too small. This is a very important feature for those with vision issues so I hope they are responsive.

Comment: Do Apple engineers not inspect the source code for this or test for this?

Comment: @user The source code is not uploaded as part of app distribution, so no one but the app developer has access to it. Apple do test apps like a user would as part of reviewing it per the [App Store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), but there are no guidelines for bad design or accessibility functionality.

Comment: Darn. I installed the app based on the [mis-impression](https://qr.ae/prG2hj) that Apple inspects the code for compliance with privacy policies.  You cited guidelines, but it doesn't describe the vetting processes.

Comment: @user Human app review is one step of the process. The primary defence against apps ‘stealing’ information from other apps is iOS itself — it does not provide the ability for apps to do this. Feel free to open a chat or look for a question on this topic specifically if you want more details.

Comment: I'm good.  Your last reply was reassuring.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm disappointed that I [cannot even report](https://www.flickr.com/photos/190456306@N08/52580813266) the violation of the app guidelines.  I moved from Android to iPhone because of my impression of the greater curation of the apps instead of a wild west.

Comment: To be fair, however, not even the native Notes app respects the text size setting.  The title of a note seems to use the requested font size, but not the text content within the note.